# Fetch records within time stamp but not specific to date

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I want to fetch records of users who signed in between 11:02 pm to 4:04 pm, date doesn't matter.

I tried something like :

```
User.where("TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '11:02:00' AND '04:04:00'")
```

But it's not working. Any help to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Created time not available on mysql.user table

Comment: are you sure ? from 11pm to 4pm ? this means you want all records excluding from 4pm : 11pm right? if yes see my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mysql between function works different than you expect.

> The between function expect the first parameter to be the min value en the second parameter to be the max value. See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Try this:

```
User.where("(TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:59:59' OR TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '03:59:59')")
```

Based on your update it will be like this:

```
User.where("(TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '23:02:00' AND '23:59:59' OR TIME(created_at) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '04:03:59')")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
User.where.not("Hour(created_at) >= '16:04' AND Hour(created_at) <= '11:02'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
User.where("DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '04:00:00'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from time_table 
   where HOUR(time_column) BETWEEN 6 AND 11
```